# How to redirect to specific port from DNS

Tags: redirect, dns, port

i've got a teamspeak 3 server from my friend, but problem is we've got to remember the ip adress if we want to connect onto it from anywhere else than home.

So I bought domain and i wanted to redirect to my teamspeak server though that domain but the problem is: everytime i want to connect to my teamspeak i have to enter Port (in my case 8020) too, and i cant enter port into DNS.

Is there any way to redirect to my teamspeak server without playing with main server?
I've seen some things with SRV record but i got no idea how to make it work.

Thanks for each response.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty nice [help page](https://support.teamspeakusa.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/293/12/does-teamspeak-3-support-dns-srv-records) on TeamSpeak's server to achieve what you are trying to do.

This page explains how it works, and the correct syntax to use to add the SRV record to your DNS zone.

According to the [following page](http://forum.teamspeak.com/showthread.php/35-Which-TCP-IP-or-UDP-PORT-does-TeamSpeak-Server-use), the default ports are TCP 8765 and UDP 8766, so you'd need the following two records:

```
_ts3._udp.yourdomain.tld. 3600 IN SRV 0 5 8766 yourdomain.tld.
_ts3._tcp.yourdomain.tld. 3600 IN SRV 0 5 8765 yourdomain.tld.
```

You should modify the ports if your TS server is not using the defaults. Also, I have no TS instance to test that myself so my answer might be inaccurate.

Comment: I already saw that but dont know how to properly make it work, not sure if i gotta use the UDP or TCc etc.

Comment: I modified my answer to try to be a bit more precise on how to forge the SRV records. The given records are valid if you modify the DNS files directly. If you use a registrar you may have to use their GUI (in which case you have to strip the "." (dots) at the end of "yourdomain.tld." (EVERYWHERE, including the _ts3.bits)

Comment: I've modified ports to one i got on my server (at least i think xx.xx.xx.xx:8020, think 8020 is port of my server, am i right?).

Comment: _ts3._tcp 3600 IN SRV 0 5 8020 toust-ts3.eu  


_ts3._udp 3600 IN SRV 0 5 8020 toust-ts3.eu

My records now look like this, not sure if i had to inport both of those so i tried it like this. Before, TS client recognized domain but could not connect to the server but after i changed records to these ones, it says "Failed to resolve hostname 'toust-ts3.eu"

Comment: According to the second link in my answer, the UDP port _MUST_ be the TCP port +1, in your case that would be 8021.
As for you domain, are you sure you didn't made a typo ? I cannot resolve it either.

Comment: Ok, as soon as i get on the site ill change it, the thing is, when i was editing dns for first time there were 2 entries with some IP adress, which disappeared after last edit, not sure what it was but i guess it was needed, is there any way to get it back?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you on that, it depends of your registrar. You should seek their advice or some help on their website.

Comment: I resolved this issue by look though history, but i still cant get it to work. I uploaded current DNS status [Here](http://www.sourcepod.com/ezwswt10-40213) .

Also im not sure if TTL in both entries is supposed to be 3600 because on the TS3 manual it say something about 86400? is that okay? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The difference with the TTL does not affect anything in a bad way (I'm just used to it to be honest). Your zone seems to be good, you might want to consider looking at your TS conf / logs to ensure that the ports are the good ones and see if it is complaining about something. You might also want to post this issue to Super User, as it seems to fit best there.

Comment: Okay, i'll post this issue to super user then.
Thanks for all your help until now!